# Solve cos(z) + sin(z) = i, where z is a complex number and i the imaginary unit

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

So yeah everything is in the title, I tried the trigonometric identity with sin(a+bi) and cos(a+bi) and I tried changing sin(z) and cos(z) for their complex expression, but all to no avail

EDIT: Thanks MPW and David! MPW's trick simplified a lot the expression and then I did like David suggested which had become much easier with this new expression

Comment: **Hint:** $\cos z+\sin z=i$, and $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can multiply and divide the left side by $\sqrt 2$ to get

$$\sqrt 2 \sin\left(z+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=i.$$

Do you know how to invert the sine function?

**Addendum 1:** You can generally write

$$a\cos z + b\sin z = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos z +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin z\right)
$$

and, since in this case, $a=b=1$,
$$\cos z + \sin z = \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos z +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin z\right)
$$

which we can recognize as
$$\cos z + \sin z = \sqrt{2}\left(\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos z +\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin z\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} +z\right)
$$

**Addendum 2:** We can find a formula for inverting sines as follows. A similar procedure works for all the trig functions. It hinges on your knowing how to invert the exponential function (*i.e.,* using logarithms) and using the quadratic formula (yes, it's valid for complex polynomials). Suppose we are given the complex number $w$ and want to solve for $z$ (I'm using a simplified version of your equation, you can substitute $\hat z = z + \pi/4$).

$$w =\sin z$$ $$w = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ $$\left(2ie^{iz}\right) w = \left(2ie^{iz}\right)\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
$$2iw(e^{iz})=(e^{iz})^2 -1$$ $$0 =(e^{iz})^2 -2iw(e^{iz}) - 1$$

This is a quadratic equation (but in $e^{iz }$) of the form $0=az^2+ bz +c$ where $a=1$, $b=-2iw$, and $c=-1$. Use the quadratic formula and simplify to get

$$e^{iz}=(2iw \pm \sqrt{-4w^2+4})/2$$ $$e^{iz}=iw\pm \sqrt{1-w ^2}$$

Now the target is in sight. To solve for $z$, all that remains is to take logarithms and divide by $i$.

Comment: From there I'd probably change the sin for it's complex expression(maybe it wouldn't change anything?). And we haven't seen arcsin(z) yet so...

Also, I don't get how you went from cos(x) + sin(x) to your expression

Comment: Your addendum is beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it in terms of exponentials:
$$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}+\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=i$$
and so
$$i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})+(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})=-2$$
and multiplying by $e^{iz}$ gives
$$(1+i)(e^{iz})^2-(1-i)=-2(e^{iz})\ .$$
Solve a quadratic to find two possible values for $e^{iz}$, then see if you can solve for $z$.

Comment: Is it legit to use the quadratic formula with complex numbers?

Comment: I did it, and it leads to a tedious path